# CRTP multiple level inheritance instantiate intermediate class with another template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, crtp

Given a multi level inheritance CRTP class structure like so, where the intermediate class B has another template parameter T, how should I instantiate an object of B?

```
template<class Derived, class T>
struct A {
    void print(T t) { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->print(t); }
};

template<template <typename> class Derived, class T>
struct B : public A<Derived<T>, T> {
    void print(T t) { cout << t << " B!\n"; }
};

template<class T>
struct C : public B<C, T> {
    void print(T t) { cout << t << " C!\n"; }
};

int main() {
    C<int> c;
    c.print(5);

    // how do I instantiate a B?
}
```

Comment: You should not instantiate `B` as separate object. Although it can be done in a sorta "hacky" way it may blow in your face when you least expect it. It is meant to be static interface and leave it that way

Comment: What do you mean by "instantiate a `B`"? `B` is not a class but a class template, representing an infinite family of classes. You can instantiate a specific member of this family - which one do you wish to instantiate? What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i have a CRTP hierarchy, where B contains some functionality that I want C to make use of thus making B a base as well. But I also want to create a B object as is to make use of it directly. One way is to create a D that inherits from B that just has an empty class body so when I do A<D<B>> d, I essentially get only B's properties out of it.